# Icon copied to drawable-hdpi is too large

Tags: android, drawable

I have a default icon in my ListView for contacts which is `96X96` the same as for Android contact thumbnails,but it appears slightly larger than them

I added the image directly to drawable-hdpi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the icon directly to drawable-hdpi,it would be better to import the image as an Android icon set,the icon is converted to drawable for mdpi and sizes above that.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the xdpi folder then it will look better